# redirecting machine hostname to fully qualified url for jira running on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jira

I'm running a Jira Instance (4.4.4) through Tomcat. However when a user navigates to 
jira/ it functions identically to when a user navigates to jira.company.com.

Is there any way to redirect the user to https://jira.company.com when they navigate to jira/ from within our network?

I have found multiple possible solutions involving 301 redirects and apache_mod_jk. Is there any way to do this directly without hiding tomcat behind mod_jk? Anyway to do this in server.xml/web.xml?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this directly with Tomcat, but it's a lot easier to use an Apache server to proxy to Tomcat using mod_jk or mod_proxy, and do the URL redirection in Apache as well.  This is especially important if your JIRA instance is accessible via the public internet; Apache is much more secure than going direct to Tomcat.